# Python - Creating a text file converting Fahrenheit to Degrees

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I've been given the task to create a program which uses a text file which contains figures in Fahrenheit, and then I need to change them into a text file which gives the figures in Degrees... Only problem is, I have no idea where to start.
Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried google? Find out how to read and write files. Start from there

Comment: You also need to be more specific in your requirements. Just how is the input text file formatted with the figures: one per line, all in one line separated by spaces, other?

Comment: *degrees Fahrenheit* into "degrees"?  What kind of degrees?  Kelvin, Rankine, Celsius?

Comment: You cannot convert _Fahrenheit to Degrees_. At all. You can convert _degrees Fahrenheit to degrees Celsius_ and vice versa.

Comment: @Matthew Morgan please mark the right post as anwser, unless it was never answered for you

Answer (score 3):

First you'll need to create a Python function to read from a text file.

Second, create a method to convert the degrees.
Then, you will create a method to write to the file the results.

This is a very broad question, and you can't expect to get the full working code. 
So start your way from the first mission, and we'll be happy to help with more problem-specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start making a python script file (a text file with *.py), and write an expression that [opens](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) your text file. You'll need to do some operations on [strings](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm) to get your lines of characters into a usable data structure (possibly a [list](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-nzzVa/0/1?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096) of floats).

Not required, but I also recommend you write a [function](http://www.learnpython.org/en/Functions) that [converts](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/8th-engage-ny/engage-8th-module-4/8th-module-4-topic-d/v/converting-farenheit-to-celsius) your units because it will make your code more readable.

Finally, you'll want to convert your numbers back into strings that can be [written](https://pythonprogramming.net/writing-file-python-3-basics/) to a file, and then of course [write](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex16.html) those lines to a file.

Check out the links I've provided as they take you to multiple learning materials for Python in general. You may find multiple answers to your problem under different tutorials, so explore!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
Fahrenheit = int(raw_input("Enter a temperature in Fahrenheit: "))
Celsius = (Fahrenheit - 32) * 5.0/9.0
print "Temperature:", Fahrenheit, "Fahrenheit = ", Celsius, " C"
```

The program asks for input as fahrenheit & converts in to celcius

Comment: This solution does not include file IO.

Comment: This solution takes user input, but the OP wants to load a text file, do math stuff, and write an output file.